# Convert Decimal to Hours Minutes and Seconds in C# .Net

Tags: c#

I have an minutes field in a database like 138.34 that I need to convert back to HH:MM:SS What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What does that number represent?  Number of hours?  Minutes?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Covert 138.34 Decimal number in Time Format like 2:18:34 (HH.MM.SS)

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(138.34).ToString("c");`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutesInDouble)`, pass the above value in double format.
For more information - check MSDN link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx)

Comment: not working...if i enter say "22.78".. its returns 22hh and 46 min

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(138.34);
int hh = timeSpan.Hours;
int mm = timeSpan.Minutes;
int ss = timeSpan.Seconds;
```

Result:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hours:{0} Minutes:{1} Seconds:{2}", hh, mm, ss);
// Hours:2 Minutes:18 Seconds:20
```